# excel formula stopped working after saving and re-opening

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a excel formula that does a formula based on data from another sheet. when i was setting it all up everything worked like a dream, the data updated when the home sheet was. I saved and closed. Now when i open it up and update the data the formula gives an #error

```
=COUNTIFS('G:\Call\[File_name_test.xlsx]CPC-Mas Nov 2013'!$M$28:$M$67,"R", 'G:\Call\[File_name_test.xlsx]CPC-Mas Nov 2013'!$C$28:$C$67, "JAC")
```

I've googled it but excel isnt my strongest!! Please help!

Comment: does it work when the `File_name_text.xlsx` is opened? See [**`this`**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/) for various ways to pull data out of different workbooks

Comment: @mehow Good god it does, So I'm guessing i need to have both books open for the link to work!I think for the purpose of this I'll leave it as is and just tell them to open both. the project is due for web migration early next year.

Comment: Gavlaaa, if you read through the link I am sure it will help you understand how to reference data in a closed workbook. It would avoid having two workbooks open which IMO would be safer and more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to data in a closed workbook using that formula.

[See alternative ways of referencing data in closed workbooks.](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/)

ie.

```
Sub ExecMacro4Excel()
    Dim path As String
    Dim workbookName As String
    Dim worksheetName As String
    Dim cell As String
    Dim returnedValue As String

    path = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\"
    workbookName = "book2.xlsm"
    worksheetName = "Sheet1"
    cell = "A1"

    returnedValue = "'" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
          worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cell).Address(True, True, -4150)

    MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro(returnedValue)
End Sub
```